# Making a Beep with "\a" in C++ not working in xcode on mac

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, terminal

I am making a program that makes a beep noise in Xcode on a MacBook pro. The speakers on my computer are on and the volume is on max yet I can't hear anything. This is my program, can you please tell me why it is not working?

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::cout << "\a";
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to make a beep noise using only "\a"?

Comment: Do you hear the beep if you run the executable from terminal, not from xcode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do this: Go to Terminal > Preferences > Settings > Advanced and tick the Audible Bell option.
See if this works!

Answer (score 3):

*Stop at any step if it works!*

1. Go to `Terminal > Preferences > Settings > Advanced` and tick the `Audible Bell` option.
2. Also make sure that in `System Preferences > Sound`, the slider for `Alert Volume` is not on its leftmost setting.
3. Try restarting your system if you've updated it.
4. Try running the generated executable on terminal instead of XCode's integrated terminal.
5. Check if terminal beeps on this command : `$ printf \\a`.

Even after all these if you don't get any beep sound then go through the steps mentioned in this [solution](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/163737). Or ask it on [Apple SE](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) or Apple Discussion Forums.

Comment: When I tried `$ printf \\a`, it said command not found. Why is this happening?

Comment: @QiuYU just open the terminal and type `printf \\a`, it should work. The `$` is just to denote a fresh line in terminal. You don't have to type that. That's probably the part that went wrong with you. Or try running `printf "\a"` or `echo -e "\a"` or `echo -e \\a`. Or you can try executing `tput bel` followed by `echo $?`, it should return 0.